# How do speed up the creation of tables, indexes and stored procs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The time to create an empty database from our source code is an issue when running our integration tests.   Is there any “tricks” to speed up the creation of database objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In adddition, consider not creating the database (detach / attach an empty one), unless this is part of your tests.

And get SSD for the drive the sql server works on. Nothing beats raw IO.

Comment: It did not speed up much with a RAM disk, so I don't think SSD will help much.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check to make sure that you have instant file initialization turned on. You have to make sure that the SQL Server service account has the "Perform volume maintenance tasks" privilege on the server.

I've also included this link for fuller instructions: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/How-to-tell-if-you-have-instant-initialization-enabled.aspx

Comment: Will this make any difference to a database that has very little data in it?

Comment: Sorry, haven't been here in a while. It could make a difference. Think about your data file. You could initialize a database at any size and only use a small portion of the overall space. Or when creating new objects and adding new data, you could roll over and trigger an auto-growth. If that auto-growth setting is high, you'll have to wait for all that disk to be initialized even if you only need a small portion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you write (or generate) a script for this and execute this on the db server itself...this will be a lot faster than doing it remotely by code.

Answer (score 0):

I create an empty database from a script and populate it from as script as well. I do it dozens of times a day, because I run my tests very frequently. It takes a few seconds on my local instance running on my workstation. Maybe you could get a faster box?

Of course, my database only has a few thousand objects, so your mileage may vary.